# Pulumi: how to create an ApplicationPassword and let Azure set the value

Tags: pulumi

I'd like to be able to do the following:

- Generate an `ApplicationPassword` without generating the actual `value` for the password (let Azure do it, similar to the way Azure generates the secret value for you in the UI, or that `secretText` is a return value from this azure api method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- Put that secret in an Azure key vault
- Redeploy the stack without having it generate a new secret everytime

Is this possible?

The reason I'd like to not specify the secret value, is that I then need to commit the secret value to code, which I don't want.

The only workaround I can think of is generating the secret value in code, storing it in keyvault, retrieving it from keyvault and using that to create the `ApplicationPassword`, but then that would cause Pulumi to create a new secret in the keyvault (and then a new `ApplicationPassword`) each time I deploy the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`RandomPassword`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/random/randompassword/) resource to generate a password that is stable between multiple runs of the same stack. It's generated once and then stored in the state file.

```ts
const password = new random.RandomPassword("password", {
    length: 16,
    special: true,
});

// use password.result somewhere
```